# Accessing iTunes podcast Directory

Tags: android, podcast

Currently trying to make a podcast app for android (currently for personal use only) however I want to be able to access the vast collection of podcasts available on iTunes is there an realistic way to access them and if not are there any good alternative with comparably large collections

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Apple iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/)

Alternatively, you could look at other directories such as...

- [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2020/03/20/introducing-podcasts-api/)
- [Listen Notes](https://www.listennotes.com/api/)